# How to generate an abi3 weel with shiboken6?

Tags: python, pyside, python-wheel, shiboken2, scikit-build

I was able to generate `cpX-cpX-manylinux_2_24` wheels using PySide2/6, shiboken2/6, scikit-build and repairwheel (https://github.com/aymara/lima-python/) but I'm not able to find where to ask to build abi3 compatible binaries.

I read in "The Python/C API, Release 3.10.5" by Guido van Rossum:

```
Py_LIMITED_API
Define this macro before including Python.h to opt in to only use the Limited API, and to select the Limited API version.
```

but in shiboken2/6 binding, I don't include Python.h myself. So I don't know where to put this define.

I read somewhere that one should define the cmake variable FORCE_LIMITED_API before building myself shiboken. But it was not a proper documentation and thus I'm not sure it is the right solution.

Comment: I think I finally found the answer. At https://github.com/qtproject/pyside-pyside-setup, there is
```
For development purposes the following options might be of use, when using setup.py build:

    --limited-api=yes|no, default yes if applicable. Set or clear the limited API flag. Ignored for Python 2.
```
So, I can just pass ` --limited-api=yes` when I build pyside or suppose it was set if using a prebuilt on and just force the wheel name to contain the `-abi3` string.
Do you think I'm right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found the answer. At github.com/qtproject/pyside-pyside-setup, there is

```
For development purposes the following options might be of use, 
when using setup.py build: --limited-api=yes|no, default yes if applicable. 
Set or clear the limited API flag. Ignored for Python 2.
```

So, I can just pass `--limited-api=yes` when I build pyside or suppose it was set if using a prebuilt one and just force the wheel name to contain the -abi3 string.